# Отследить изменение высоты textarea

Tags: javascript

Как отслеживать факт изменения textarea по высоте? В примере кнопки 1 и 2 вносят текст, а кнопка 3 - удаляет. Делаю кроссбраузерно на pure js. Текст будет вносится / удаляться с виртуальной клавиатуры.

```js
let d = document.getElementById('tarea');

function f1() {
  d.innerHTML += 'qwerty';
  d.focus();
}

function f2() {
  d.innerHTML += 'ASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMQWERTYUIOP';
  d.focus();
}

function f3() {
  d.innerHTML = '';
  d.style.height = 24 + 'px';
}
```

```css
#tarea {
  width: 28%;
  height: 24px;
  background: yellowgreen;
  padding: 0% 0% 0% 1%;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="f1()">1.ins</button>
  <button onclick="f2()">2.ins</button>
  <button onclick="f3()">3.del</button>
</div>
<br>
<textarea id="tarea" rows="1" autofocus onfocusin="this.style.height = 'auto';this.style.height = this.scrollHeight +10+ 'px';" placeholder="Внести текст"></textarea>
```

Comment: Нашёл такое: https://javascriptio.com/view/38160/resize-event-for-textarea пытаюсь прикрутить без лишнего ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Comment: @Aziz Umarov, да, спасибо, только прикрутить на pure js пока не получилось ... делал через `d.addEventListener("input", OnInput, false);` по Вашей ссылке `OPTION 2` не подскажете как правильно сделать?

Comment: OPTION 2 это jQuery.fn.extend({
  autoHeightTextarea: function()?